# Regarding computed values in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

Consider the following piece of code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/<Computed Value>/samples/home.js"></script>
```

In the above example, how does  'Computed Value'  get populated. I mean what is the general way of doing it in extjs?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Ext.String.format function: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.String-method-format. It should do what you need:

```
var cls = 'my-class',
    text = 'Some text';
var s = Ext.String.format('<div class="{0}">{1}</div>', cls, text);
// s now contains the string: '<div class="my-class">Some text</div>'
```